# Automate backing up of MySQL DB on Godaddy Windows account

Tags: mysql, backups, godaddy

Does anyone know of a good way to set up an automated backup of our MySQL DB on a Godaddy Windows account?  Most articles I have found talk about using mysqldump.  But I can't figure out how to do that in a Windows environment.  There is a task scheduler in the account settings with plenty of options for when to run the task.  There is also a line for "Path to an executable file" and a line for "Arguments".  Talking with Godaddy support, all they tell me is that I can run an aspx file or a php file in the task scheduler.  No more details.  Has anyone done this before?

Update: What I am trying to do is what this guy did: http://www.htpcbeginner.com/automatic-mysql-database-backup-on-godaddy/
He created a bash script to run as a cron job that does automatic daily, weekly, and monthly backups.  The script will also automatically delete the old backups based on configured settings.  So I guess my options are to emulate this script in a aspx or php file, correct?

Answer (score -1):

Happy to help here. I am a product manager on our Plesk hosting (windows) team at GoDaddy. If you are using our Plesk windows hosting, you can do this through the backup manager.

1.) Log into Plesk

2.) Click on backup manager on the right side panel

3.) Click to 'More Actions'

4.) Click on 'Schedule Backup Settings'

5.) Set backup content to Domain configuration and content

This will backup the entire site, not just the databases.  We do not currently have a way to backup just the database. We have requested that Plesk add this feature in a future version.

Hope this helps! If you are not using Plesk, reach out to me and I will see what I can do to get you an answer.

Update: Yes this is automated. You can set it to daily, weekly, monthly. The only issue is that it will do the entire site, not just the databases. If you do just the databases, it is a one click process but is not automated.

Update 2: Although the solution stated above is automated (you can set it to daily, weekly, monthly), the backup will backup the entire site, not just the databases.

If you want just the databases, you are correct. The best option is to do as you mention, and recreate the script in a language that can be used on our servers.

Comment: Is this "automated"?

Comment: Downvote, as this doesn't appear to be automated, as the OP was asking for.

Comment: I am using Plesk.  I need it to be automated because I will never remember to do this every day, week, month, etc.